# How to reduce the width of menu item using the Foundation framework

Tags: html, css, menu, zurb-foundation

I've been creating a menu using the Foundation framework, however I noticed that each of the menu items have a large width(the home tab, that's what it looks like when I hover over it): 
[image]

Is there anyway to reduce this spacing? I've tried using padding, but to no avail. Should I be changing something in Foundation's CSS files? (I'm comfortable with SASS).

Here's what I have:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">volunteer</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.top-bar {
     height: 125px;
     font-family: ProximaNova;
     font-size: 16px;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(white), to(#f0f0f0));
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #f0f0f0);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #f0f0f0);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, white, #f0f0f0);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, #f0f0f0);
}
.top-bar ul li a {
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Here's the site: http://mvcsf.com/new/
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to reduce the padding. Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 940px)
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
padding: 0px 7px;
line-height: 125px;
background: url("../img/headerbackground.png") repeat-x;
```

Or add this:

```
.top-bar-section ul li a {padding:0px 3px !important}
```